# How to install a Google web font onto my Linux computer?

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts, libreoffice

I need to install a [Google font](http://www.google.com/fonts) for use in Libre Office. I search through the web and found a solution meant for [Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/automatically-install-all-google-web.html). I am using Fedora, which works differently. And also, I only need one font, not all of them. Is there any way I can install it? I note that Google provides the fonts in `.woff` format. Is it compatible for use in Libre Office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the TTF format version that they also provide via *Add to Collection*, *Download files* then *Download the font families in your Collection as a .zip file*. Unzip that `.zip` file and then place those files in your `~/.fonts` directory, create the directory first if it doesn't exist, and then restart LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The download button is so hard to find.